# Remove click event listener set by another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

With the Chrome developer tools I have found a click event listener I'd like to remove:

[image]

If I remove the listener with the developer tools it works. Now I've figured out that the listener is added via jQuery:

```
$(".js_playerlist").on("click",".playerlist_item",function(){
    var a=$(this).hasClass("nothingThere");
    if(!a) { 
        var d=$(this).data("msgid");
        if(d) { 
            b.loadChatLogWithPlayer(this,d)
        } else {
            b.loadChatLogWithPlayer(this)
        }
    }
});
```

How can I remove this event listener via Javascript **without jQuery**?

Comment: You have access to jQuery because the handler was set using that, so why do you not want to use jQuery?

Comment: Because it is a Chrome/Firefox extension I'm writing, I can't jQuery from the site itself, can I?

Comment: So long as you wait until jQuery gets loaded, I don't see why not. There are a number of extensions that act in the context of a loaded page, so it seems that's a thing that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to jQuery function to do this because the event is attached by jquery so use **[`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)** or **[`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** the both functions remove the event :

```
$(".js_playerlist").delay(1000).off("click",".playerlist_item");
//OR
$(".js_playerlist").delay(1000).unbind( "click.playerlist_item" );
```

You could use a javascript method `removeEventListener()` but you have to pass the function you want to remove as parameter and the way that the script attaching the event in your case avoid that.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither `.off()` nor `.unbind()` did work. The click event still triggers. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like the event listener is attached after I use `.off()`. So I have to run it, once the elements are fully loaded and all listeners are attached.

Comment: That doesn't work somehow. If I open the page and type in your code in the javascript console, it works. But executing the code in the extension doesn't. I even tried creating a script DOM element and putting the code in there. The code is executed but it doesn't happen anything.

Comment: I solved it now by putting the code in a script DOM element and executing it with `window.setTimeout`. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("js_playerlist")[0].removeEventListener("click", attachedFunction);
```

In this case `attachedFunction` is the function that is attached to be called when the event triggers. In your case:

```
function(){
    var a=$(this).hasClass("nothingThere");
    if(!a) { 
        var d=$(this).data("msgid");
        if(d) { 
            b.loadChatLogWithPlayer(this,d)
        } else {
            b.loadChatLogWithPlayer(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly, if you have access to the code, extract the function and assign it to a variable, the code will be cleaner.

If the other script is not under your onwership, in order to be 100% easy to maintain, I would propose that you send a request for the other script code and parse it to get the desired function, so you will have the latest version all the time.